# Removing strings outside of parentheses in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dataframe

I have a dataset and need to remove parentheses from some rows within a column.

```
  test
 (ABC)
 ABC(DEF)G
 ABC
```

Desired Output

```
  test
  ABC
  DEF
  ABC
```

This is what I tried: `df['test'] = df['test'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')` When I do this it deletes the rows without parentheses all together. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried this and it erased all strings without parentheses

Comment: @user19077881 That sorta worked the parentheses are gone but I have all the characters outside the parentheses still present.

Comment: Right, sorry. `df['test'].str.replace(r'.*?\((.*)\).*', r'\1', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['test'].str.replace(r'.*?\((.*)\).*', r'\1', regex=True)
# or a bit more efficient
df['test'].str.replace(r'[^(]*\((.*)\).*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

The point is to get to the first `(`, then capture all text after it till the last `)`, and then match the rest of the string, and then remove all text outside of the parentheses.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0YYqU3/1).

There can be more variations depending on the requirements.

*Pattern details*:

- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.